# Using PaperJS I have a tangent point and a normal point in PaperJS - how do I calculate the point needed (see image)

Tags: vector, paperjs, calculation

I imported a svg in PaperJS and let it move along a path.
As it moves along the path, I calculate the rotation to let it follow the path with the right rotation.

Now I need a point that is offset from the svg.

Please have a look at this image for a better understanding of what I need:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gNdg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I already found it out. If anyone is interested here is the answer:

Add the two points together (offset points of normal and tangent) then add the point of the svg.

```
var normal = this.strecke.getNormalAt(offset)

    var normalOffset = normal.multiply(Math.random() * (this.bubbleOffsetX -  (-1)*this.bubbleOffsetX + 1) + (-1)*this.bubbleOffsetX)
    var tanOffset = tangent.multiply(this.bubbleOffsetY)

    var bubblePosition = normalOffset.add(tanOffset).add(point)

    var bubble = new Path.Circle({
      center: bubblePosition,
      radius: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.bubbleMaxSize - this.bubbleMinSize + 1) + this.bubbleMinSize),
      fillColor: '#A4F2FB',
      opacity: Math.random > 50 ? .5 : .3,
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      bubble.remove()
    }, this.bubbleLifespan);
```